# C# TableLayoutPanel - populate and duplicate row controls

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

OK - here I am again - C# newbie par excellence!

Assume I have a **TableLayoutPanel** as shown - with a single row, and a number of columns...
I populate that single row with controls (labels, textboxes etc).

Now I want to *duplicate* that row 'n' times, and index each of the controls as a member of an array (of controls) - e.g. labelName[rowIndex].Text = "New Text"

- is there a better way to do it...?

[image: 1]]
Many thanks - my last attempt at doing this was many years ago with VB6!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to create a `List<List<Control>>`.  Then each row that you populate the tablelayoutpanel will be in a `List<Control>`. Assuming 3 columns it would look something like this:

```
List<List<Control>> contrlList = new List<List<Control>>();
for (int row = 0; row < tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount; row++)
{
    List<Control> rowControls = new List<Control>()
        {
            new DateTimePicker(),
            new TextBox(),
            new Label()
        };
    for (int col = 0; col < tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount; col++)
    {
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(rowControls[col], col, row);
        contrlList.Add(rowControls);
    }
}
```

To access common properties you would call it like this:

```
contrlList[0][1].Text = "Whatever";
```

To get the specific properties unique to each type of control, you'll have to cast it to the proper type:

```
((DateTimePicker)contrlList[0][0]).CalendarTitleBackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
```

To create event handlers that each type of control can use, load one of that type in the designer.  Over in the property window, in the header, is an icon that looks like a lightning bolt.  This brings up a list of events that this type of control will have.  Double click on the event you want to handle.  This will create a snippet in the code. Rename the method so that it doesn't point to a particular instance of that control(i.e ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged instead of comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged).  Now it's a simple matter of adding that event handler so that the control knows where to for that event.

```
List<List<Control>> contrlList = new List<List<Control>>();
for (int row = 0; row < tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount; row++)
{
    DateTimePicker newDTP = new DateTimePicker();
    ComboBox newCB = new ComboBox();
    newCB.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
    Label newL = new Label();
    List<Control> rowControls = new List<Control>()
        {
            newDTP,
            newCB,
            newL
        };
    for (int col = 0; col < tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount; col++)
    {
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(rowControls[col], col, row);
        contrlList.Add(rowControls);
    }
}
```

Comment: OK - let me think about that!  It all makes sense, but less intuitive / readable than I expected.

Comment: Yeah, I like the relative simplicity of this.
I know the list control was suggested above, but your post is more readable for a dork like myself!

Comment: I've managed to get this working, but I have anoher twist, which may solve a few questions in general... Assuming some of the loaded Controls are comboBoxes... how can I populate them (and get an event when it changes.

Comment: I added more for you.  For populating the comboboxes cast the control in the list, at the row,column indexes that are ComboBoxes, to ComboBox, as per my example, and add items like any combobox.

Comment: Thanks - while you were at it - I also figured it out. - MANY THANKS